# What is the proper (efficient) way to write this function?

Tags: haskell, recursion, data-structures, tree, complexity-theory

The following function returns a list of possible paths starting from the root node to the deepest node of a tree:

```
paths :: Tree a -> [[a]]
paths (Node element []) = [[element]]
paths (Node element children) = map (element :) $ concat $ map paths children
```

This looks very inefficient on paper, since `concat` has terrible complexity. Can this function be rewritten in a way that keeps the complexity lower without using intermediate data structures (like sequence)?

EDIT: to be honest, I know one could avoid the O(n)/loop complexity of concat by:

1. Building the path (list) as you go down on the recursion;
2. Only when you reach the last recursion level, append the path to a global "result" list.

Here is a JavaScript implementation that illustrates this algorithm:

```
function paths(tree){
    var result = [];
    (function go(node,path){
        if (node.children.length === 0)
            result.push(path.concat([node.tag]));
        else
            node.children.map(function(child){
                go(child,path.concat([node.tag]));
            });
    })(tree,[]);
    return result;
}
console.log(paths(
    {tag: 1,
    children:[
        {tag: 2, children: [{tag: 20, children: []}, {tag: 200, children: []}]},
        {tag: 3, children: [{tag: 30, children: []}, {tag: 300, children: []}]},
        {tag: 4, children: [{tag: 40, children: []}, {tag: 400, children: []}]}]}));
```

*(It is not actually O(1)/iteration since I used `Array.concat` instead of lists consing (JS has no built-in lists), but just using it instead would make it constant-time per iteration.)*

Comment: [`DList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.3/docs/Data-DList.html) should emulate the performance of the global solution you describe -- it's the functional equivalent of mutating a list cons (as long as it is only consumed once)

Comment: ... I'm not sure how? I'd love to see an answer! :) also - if you just use the list monad like this: "do { x <- map f xs; x }", and then, on the most deep iteration, cons to a normal list on IORef, would this do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`concat` does not have terrible complexity; it is `O(n)`, where `n` is the total number of elements in each list but the last. In this case, I don't think it's possible to do any better, with or without an intermediate structure, unless you change the type of the result. The list of lists, in this context, offers absolutely no potential for sharing, so you have no choice but to allocate each "cons" of each list. The `concatMap` only adds a constant factor overhead, and I'd be surprised if you could find a way to reduce that significantly.

If you want to use some sharing (at the cost of structural laziness), you can indeed switch to a different data structure. This will only matter if the tree is somewhat "bushy". Any sequence type supporting `snoc` will do. At the simplest, you can even use lists *in reverse*, so you get paths leading from the leaves to the root instead of the other way around. Or you can use something more flexible like `Data.Sequence.Seq`:

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import Data.Sequence ((|>), Seq)
import qualified Data.DList as DL
import Data.Tree

paths :: Tree a -> [Seq a]
paths = DL.toList . go S.empty
  where
    go s (Node a []) = DL.singleton (s |> a)
    go s (Node a xs) = let sa = s |> a
                       in sa `seq` DL.concat . map (go sa) $ xs
```

#### Edit

As Viclib and delnan point out, there was a problem with my original answer, because the bottom level got traversed multiple times.

Comment: One invocation of `concat` takes O(n) time, but since it's being used at each level of recursion, the complexity of `paths` is worse (I'm too lazy to figure out what exactly). Also, "terrible" is relative, but there are certainly persistent sequential containers with better (logarithmic or amortized constant, for concatenating two lists) complexity.

Comment: @delnan, the `concat` is applied at each level to the elements one level below, so the sum of all the steps in the concats follows the total number of elements in the tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I do think that it can be done in constant time per iteration - maybe using ST - since you can in another language. I've edited the main post with what I have in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: @Viclib, I'm not sure what you mean by "per iteration". The solution I gave is `O(n)`, where `n` is the total number of elements in the tree. There is no way to do better than that in any language.

Comment: No, I mean - your solution involves using another data structure. If I get it, it is perfectly fine and a great way to do it - but I'm specifically asking if this can be done with lists alone. Mostly for learning purposes.

Comment: @dfeuer Not the elements are concatenated, the results of `paths element`, which includes many copies of said elements (except for leaves). In fact, the root of a full binary tree with depth d, there are 2 child elements but `concat $ map paths elements` has 2^(d-1) elements, give or take a few, most of which have already been copied several times by previous `concat` calls.

Comment: @delnan, it should be fixed now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6):

Let's benchmark:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Control.DeepSeq
import Criterion.Main
import Data.Sequence ((|>), Seq)
import Data.Tree
import GHC.DataSize
import qualified Data.DList as DL
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

-- original version
pathsList :: Tree a -> [[a]]
pathsList = go where
  go (Node element []) = [[element]]
  go (Node element children) = map (element:) (concatMap go children)

-- with reversed lists, enabling sharing of path prefixes
pathsRevList :: Tree a -> [[a]]
pathsRevList = go [] where
  go acc (Node a []) = [a:acc]
  go acc (Node a xs) = concatMap (go (a:acc)) xs

-- dfeuer's version
pathsSeqDL :: Tree a -> [Seq a]
pathsSeqDL = DL.toList . go S.empty
  where
    go s (Node a []) = DL.singleton (s |> a)
    go s (Node a xs) = let sa = s |> a
                       in sa `seq` DL.concat . map (go sa) $ xs

-- same as previous but without DLists. 
pathsSeq :: Tree a -> [Seq a]
pathsSeq = go S.empty where
  go acc (Node a []) = [acc |> a]
  go acc (Node a xs) = let acc' = acc |> a
                       in acc' `seq` concatMap (go acc') xs

genTree :: Int -> Int -> Tree Int
genTree branch depth = go 0 depth where
  go n 0 = Node n []
  go n d = Node n [go n' (d - 1) | n' <- [n .. n + branch - 1]]

memSizes = do
  let !tree = force $ genTree 4 4      
  putStrLn "sizes in memory"
  putStrLn . ("list: "++) . show =<< (recursiveSize $!! pathsList tree)
  putStrLn . ("listRev: "++) . show =<< (recursiveSize $!! pathsRevList tree)
  putStrLn . ("seq: "++) . show =<< (recursiveSize $!! pathsSeq tree)
  putStrLn . ("tree itself: "++) . show =<< (recursiveSize $!! tree)

benchPaths !tree = do
  defaultMain [
    bench "pathsList" $ nf pathsList tree,
    bench "pathsRevList" $ nf pathsRevList tree,
    bench "pathsSeqDL" $ nf pathsSeqDL tree,
    bench "pathsSeq" $ nf pathsSeq tree
    ]  

main = do
  memSizes
  putStrLn ""
  putStrLn "normal tree"
  putStrLn "-----------------------"
  benchPaths (force $ genTree 6 8)
  putStrLn "\ndeep tree"
  putStrLn "-----------------------"  
  benchPaths (force $ genTree 2 20)
  putStrLn "\nwide tree"
  putStrLn "-----------------------"  
  benchPaths (force $ genTree 35 4)
```

Some notes:

- I benchmark on on GHC 7.8.4 with -O2 and -fllvm.
- I fill the tree in `genTree` with some `Int`-s in order to prevent GHC optimization causing subtrees to be shared.
- In `memSizes` the tree must be pretty small, because `recursiveSize` has quadratic complexity.

Results on my Core i7 3770:

```
sizes in memory
list: 37096
listRev: 14560
seq: 26928
tree itself: 16576

normal tree
-----------------------
pathsList               372.9 ms   
pathsRevList            213.6 ms   
pathsSeqDL              962.2 ms   
pathsSeq                308.8 ms   

deep tree
-----------------------
pathsList               554.1 ms   
pathsRevList            266.7 ms   
pathsSeqDL              919.8 ms   
pathsSeq                438.4 ms   

wide tree
-----------------------
pathsList               191.6 ms   
pathsRevList            129.1 ms   
pathsSeqDL              448.2 ms   
pathsSeq                157.3 ms
```

Comments:

- I am entirely unsurprised. The original version with lists is asymptotically optimal for the job. Also, it makes sense to use `DList` only when we would otherwise have inefficient list appends, but it's not the case here.
- Note that the list of reversed paths takes less space than the tree itself.
- The performance patterns are consistent over differently shaped trees. In the "deep tree" case `Seq` performs relatively worse, presumably because `Seq` snoc is costlier than list cons.
- I think a Clojure-style persistent vector (Int-indexed shallow tries) would be nice here, since they can be pretty fast, can possibly have less space overhead than plain lists and support efficient snoc and random reads/writes. In comparison, `Seq` is heavier in weight, though it supports a wider range of efficient operations.

Comment: exactly. `foldl (++)` is bad; `foldr (++)` (and so, `concat`) is perfectly fine.

Comment: I think your trees are much too small to reflect some of the differences between these algorithms. Using fewer benchmarks of deeper/bushier trees may be interesting. It would also be good to add a `revList` version using `DList` (or something). I say "or something" because I'm also trying to find a nice way to transform the `DList`s away while using that same essential algorithm.

Comment: @dfeuer: my 6-branching 8-depth tree has 6^8 ~ 1,6 million nodes, that's surely not too small! Anyway, I added results for wide and deep trees too, and the overall picture remains the same.

Comment: Interesting. I'm still trying to understand why the `DList`s are hurting performance for the reversed lists. I'll need to think about this more.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of algorithm optimization, not code optimization: tree by definition has only one path from root to any node, there is no need to return a list in first place. It only makes sense if you want to return paths to all deepest nodes, if there are many of them on the same depth.

Comment: Actually, your code returns paths not to the deepest nodes, but to the all leaf nodes, depth isn't taken into account at all.

Comment: ... yes, that is what I mean. I meant terminal nodes. I'm not a native english speaker, but I see your confusion.